# Configuration settings in installation process of nginx,mysql,php5 (LINUX)

Tags: linux, nginx

PHP, MySQL is installed and working fine.
There are some modifications in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf` file

```
Uncommented 54,55,61,62,63,64
added 8080 port in 21 line 
commented 22 line 
change the path in 23 line to /var/www/html/ 
line number 25 , add index.php into the list.
```

After all this I restarted nginx server then I got this Error.

> Using service nginx restart
>
> nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "Location" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:54
>
> nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to configure nginx

Comment: I fixed this issue. While editing default.conf file I added Location in place of location. That's why i got directive not found error.  I corrected this. No issues working fine.